# Pandas - How to remove rows following a defined step?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame of 600 rows by 2 columns (wavelength and intensity), I want to delete some rows following a step defined for the wavelength. In my case I want 2 options of step : 1 nm or 5 nm. The good thing is that the wavelength column of my DataFrame has a step of 0.5 nm so it is possible to keep 1 out of 2 for 1nm step and 1 out of 10 for the 5nm step. But I struggle to express this "x out of y" thing in code.

I started to do a program that ask the required step (+ other stuff with pandas) but now I am blocked.

Do you have any idea/advice to give me so I can realise what I explained above ?

Thank you very much to you all !

EDIT: here is the 15 first value of my dataframe (first column starts from 207 because I reshaped the the dataframe and deleted some values) it starts from 400nm and it goes to 700nm ( I forgot this before sorry)

```
      Wavelength Intensity
207     400.00    38.000
208     400.50    40.000
209     401.00    39.000
210     401.50    38.000
211     402.00    39.000
212     402.50    41.000
213     403.00    40.000
214     403.50    40.000
215     404.00    41.000
216     404.50    41.000
217     405.00    40.000
218     405.50    42.000
219     406.00    42.000
220     406.50    41.000
221     407.00    43.000
```

What I want, for a 5 nm step, is :

```
      Wavelength Intensity
207     400.00    38.000
217     405.00    40.000
...
807     700.00    52.000
```

Maybe it will help with my whole code because nothing that has been proposed is working.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Reading the data file
df = pd.read_csv('bridgelux-27s-NC.csv')

# Reshaping the dataframe to 400-700nm
df.drop(df.head(207).index, inplace=True)
df.drop(df.tail(399).index, inplace=True)

# Rename the columns
df = df.rename(columns={"Excitation mode": "Wavelength",
                        "None": "Intensity"})

nm = 5
out = df[df['Wavelength'] % nm == 0]
```

Comment: Please provide some sample data and the expected result / layout.

Comment: yes sure sorry I forgot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reproduce let me do

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(0)
wavelength = np.random.randint(200, 600, 100) + np.random.choice([0, .5], 100)
intensity = np.random.randint(0, 100, 100)

df = pd.DataFrame({'wavelength': wavelength, 'intensity': intensity})
```

Now you can downsample to 1nm or 5nm

```
# downsample to 1nm
df['wavelength_1'] = df.wavelength - df.wavelength % 1

# downsample to 5nm
df['wavelength_5'] = df.wavelength - df.wavelength % 5
```

Then, you can decide to simply drop duplicates (but you have to decide which one you want to keep)

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset='wavelength_1', keep='first')
```

or to group by downsampled wavelengths and take a stat (mean, median)

```
df.groupby('wavelength_1')[['intensity']].median()
```

Comment: I got this error `TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting`

Comment: @Théodore which line gives you this error?

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
df.head()

    wavelength  intensity
0          0.5         10
1          1.0         11
2          1.5         12
3          2.0         13
4          2.5         14
5          3.0         15
6          3.5         16
7          4.0         17
8          4.5         18
9          5.0         19
10         5.5         20
11         6.0         21
12         6.5         22
13         7.0         23
14         7.5         24
15         8.0         25
16         8.5         26
17         9.0         27
18         9.5         28
19        10.0         29

df_1nm = df[df["wavelength"]%1 == 0]

    wavelength  intensity
1          1.0         11
3          2.0         13
5          3.0         15
7          4.0         17
9          5.0         19
11         6.0         21
13         7.0         23
15         8.0         25
17         9.0         27
19        10.0         29

df_5nm = df[df["wavelength"]%5 == 0]

    wavelength  intensity
9          5.0         19
19        10.0         29
```

where `df` is your dataframe with the two columns `wavelength` and `intensity`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What does the `%1 (or5) == 0` means ?

Comment: I'm not sure this is want you want to do, but here what  `df["wavelength"]%1 == 0 ` is doing is that it's creating a pandas.Series of the same size as `df` for each value contained in `df["wavelength"]` if the rest of the euclidian division of this value by `1` (or `5`) is equal to zero it return `True` else it return `False`

Comment: I will try your code and see what it does thank you

Comment: I modified my answer so that you can see what is the output for each line. 
Note that if you want to filter out the value for 1nm or 5nm instead of only keep these values you can do `df[df["wavelength"]%1 != 0]`

Comment: I understand, but like all answers here I got the error `TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting`

Comment: @Théodore I think you Wavelength column contains string and not float or int, try casting it before doing `df['Wavelength'] % nm == 0` using something like `df['Wavelength'] = df['Wavelength'].astype(float)`